# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Promise<Void>' to return type 'Promise<JSON>' Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, promisekit

I am new to PromiseKit and am having trouble getting the value of the Promise. The end goal is to have the async call resolve to an array of JSON. Currently the compiler is complaining that:

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Promise<Void>' to return type 'Promise<JSON>'`

I am pretty confused, and haven't been able to find a solution that looks like what I have going. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Here is the get method that makes the call to my backend for Json data.

```
public func get(_ url: URL) -> Promise<JSON> {
    return Promise<JSON> { resolver -> Void in

      Alamofire.request(url)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
          switch response.result {
          case .success(let json):
            let json = JSON()
            if let data = response.data {
              guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else {
                resolver.reject("Error" as! Error)
                return
              }
              resolver.fulfill(json)
            }
          case .failure(let error):
            resolver.reject(error)
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the method that uses the above method:

```
public func fetchAllocations() -> Promise<JSON> {
    let url: URL = createAllocationsUrl()
    var allocations = JsonArray()

    let responsePromise = httpClient.get(url).done { (fetchedJSON) in
      let fetchedAlloc: JsonArray = JSON(fetchedJSON).array ?? []
      if fetchedAlloc.count > 0 {

        let eid = "9b0e33b869"
        let previousAlloc = self.store.get(eid)

        if let previousAllocations = previousAlloc {
          if previousAllocations.count > 0 {
            allocations = Allocations.reconcileAllocations(previousAllocations, allocations)
          }
        }
        self.store.set(eid, val: allocations)
        self.allocationStatus = AllocationStatus.RETRIEVED

        if self.confirmationSandbagged {
          self.eventEmitter.confirm(allocations)
        }
      }
    }
    return responsePromise
  }
```

And in the button of my view controller, I am executing that function as so:

```
    // This should be a Promise<JSON> that I can resolve and fulfill
    let promise = alloc.fetchAllocations().done { (json) in
      self.allocations = [json]
    }
    let eid = "9b0e33b869"
    let cached = store.get(eid)
    print("YOUR FETCHED ALLOCATION: \(String(describing: self.allocations))")
    print("YOUR CACHED ALLOCATION: \(String(describing: cached))")
```

When I get to my print statements, I have nil each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public func fetchAllocations() -> Promise<[JSON]> {

    return Promise { resolve in
      let url = self.createAllocationsUrl()

      let strPromise = HttpClient.get(url: url).done { (stringJSON) in
        var allocations = JSON.init(parseJSON: stringJSON).arrayValue
        let previous = self.store.get(self.participant.getUserId())

        if let prevAlloc = previous {
          if Allocator.allocationsNotEmpty(allocations: prevAlloc) {
            allocations = Allocations.reconcileAllocations(previousAllocations: prevAlloc, currentAllocations: allocations)
          }
        }

        self.store.set(self.participant.getUserId(), val: allocations)
        self.allocationStatus = AllocationStatus.RETRIEVED

        if (self.confirmationSandbagged) {
          self.eventEmitter.confirm(allocations: allocations)
        }

        if self.contaminationSandbagged {
          self.eventEmitter.contaminate(allocations: allocations)
        }
        resolve.fulfill(allocations)
        do {
          try self.execution.executeWithAllocation(rawAllocations: allocations)
        } catch let err {
          let message = "There was an error executing with allocations. \(err.localizedDescription)"
          Log.logger.log(.error, message: message)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```